# ND4J cosine distance больше единицы

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

Вот код:

```
double dist = Transforms.cosineDistance(currentVector, publicVector);
```

Но значение переменной dist больше единицы. Почему? 
Вот краткий пример кода:

```
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j;
import org.nd4j.linalg.ops.transforms.Transforms;
INDArray v1 = Nd4j.create(new double[]{1, 2, -30000});
INDArray v2 = Nd4j.create(new double[]{1, 2, 3});
double dist = Transforms.cosineDistance(v1, v2);
System.out.println(dist); // 1.80173921585083
```

При более маленьких значениях массивов всё нормально. Но что же я делаю не так?

Comment: подозреваю, что это проекция одного вектора на другой

Comment: @Igor, но почему значение положительное, если проекция любого из этих векторов на другой будет отрицательной?

Comment: @igor, возможно, я понял. Если найти настоящее значение косинуса этого угла, то оно будет равно 1-dist. Но зачем так сделано -- непонятно